# Input string was not in a correct format. Textbox value

Tags: c#

I have this method.

```
public static long? GetPayments(int PaymentId,string Reference)
        
{

          
            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connstrig))
                {
                    con.Open();
                    DynamicParameters param = new DynamicParameters();
                    param.Add("@IDPayment", PaymentId);
                    param.Add("@Ref", Reference);
                    var result = con.Query<long?>("spc_PaymentStatusForCombo", param, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).FirstOrDefault();
                    return result;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                ApplicationLog.WriteLog("spc_PaymentStatusForCombo", exc.Message, "Error");
                return null;
            }
        }
```

And when i call it this error is shown up:Input string was not in a correct format.

```
var result = 
GetPaymentsByPayId(Convert.ToInt32(txt_IdPayment.Text.Trim()), (txt_IdPayment.Text.Length > 0) ? (txt_OrderID.Text.Trim()) : string.Empty);
```

Can you help me please? Thank you

Comment: are you sure that `txt_IdPayment.Text` is a valid Int32 ?

Comment: the problem is with txt_OrderID.Text.Trim()

Comment: is this a Win Forms app?, do you call this function in `TextChanged Event`  ?

Comment: yes it is a win form. No i call it in a method, which then i call in click of an button

Comment: the only thing I can think about is that `txt_IdPayment.Text`, try to debug your code and check the value of `txt_IdPayment.Text`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is clear, the string input is not correct.

You can have this error for example if you try Convert.ToInt32("");

According to your method's structure, you should send an int value as the first parameter and the Convert.ToInt32(txt_IdPayment.Text.Trim()) must cause this exception.

Check what it returns txt_IdPayment.Text.Trim().

Comment: txt_IdPayment.Text.Trim() without Convert.ToInt32 shows error

Comment: Weird! Are you sure?

Comment: yeah i tried now again. If i delete Convert.ToInt32 it shows the error can not convert from string to int

Comment: No, this is another error. If you send a string to your method, you will have this exception. Can you try to get it in a parameter before calling your method ? For example var id = txt_IdPayment.Text.Trim();

Comment: thank you. When i did this var id, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = GetPaymentsByPayIdorMidasreference(Convert.ToInt32((txt_IdPayment.Text.Length > 0) ? txt_IdPayment.Text.Trim() : "0"), (txt_IdPayment.Text.Length > 0) ? (txt_OrderID.Text.Trim()) : string.Empty);
```

Comment: This is not a good solution Amit. In case of something nonconvertible to int you will get the same error. For example, if the input text is ABC, you will have the same error and if the length is 0, you will get a false result. You should check what you send to your method before.

Comment: If we restrict our input type to accept only numeric value then it will work.

Comment: Yes but, you can not restrict the textbox without a specific code. And we don't know the context and where the ID comes from into the textbox.